Do I need to change the configuration in docker for using ASPOSE WORDS library in dotnet?
I am using Aspose Pdf library for converting HTML code to PDF Document in Dotnet. In Windows this is working perfectly  but in docker image it is showing an error in the second line - 
var options = new HtmlLoadOptions();

var pdfDocument = new Document(stream, options);
Here Document is using from Aspose and the steam is - 
var stream = new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(HtmlData)
do I need any configuration for Aspose in the docker file?

Aspose.Words for .NET Core and .NET Standard uses SkiaSharp to deal with graphics, to make it work on Linux you have to add reference either to SkiaSharp.NativeAssets.Linux or to SkiaSharp.NativeAssets.Linux.NoDependencies
If you add reference to SkiaSharp.NativeAssets.Linux, you should also install libfontconfig1 in your system. SkiaSharp.NativeAssets.Linux depends on this library. You can use the following command to install it:
apt-get update && apt-get install -y libfontconfig1

If you do not have rights to install packages, or other reasons not to install libfontconfig1, you can simply use SkiaSharp.NativeAssets.Linux.NoDependencies, which does not require installation of libfontconfig1.
For your reference here is simple working Dokerfile and .csproj:
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:7.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libfontconfig1

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["TestNet7.csproj", "."]
RUN dotnet restore "./TestNet7.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "TestNet5.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "TestNet7.csproj" -c Release -r linux-x64 --no-self-contained -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final

WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "TestNet7.dll"]

<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>
  </PropertyGroup>
  
   <PropertyGroup>
     <InvariantGlobalization>false</InvariantGlobalization>
   </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
      <PackageReference Include="Aspose.Words" Version="24.5.0" />
      <PackageReference Include="SkiaSharp.NativeAssets.Linux.NoDependencies" Version="2.88.7" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>


After adding the nuget "SkiaSharp.NativeAssets.Linux.NoDependencies" I am getting the same error "Object reference is not set" and "apt-get update && apt-get install -y libfontconfig1"  is showing "System drawing.common is not supported on this platform"

Aspose.Words does not have dependency on System.Drawing.Common. Do you use other Aspose product in your project? Which version do you use? I would suggest to post the question in the Aspose.Words support forum https://forum.aspose.com/c/words/8 and attach sample project that will allow to reproduce the problem.

Use Aspose.Pdf.Drawing instead of Aspose.PDF for .NET and make sure that you install msttcorefonts package as well [Forum] and [Overview]
Aspose.PDF.Drawing library successfully works on the Docker platform that allows you to package into a container your application.The ‘ttf-mscorefonts-installer’ and ‘fontconfig’ packages are needed for successful work Aspose.PDF.Drawing for .NET library in Docker
You can see the examples from here and here
